# Flutter icons do not show

Tags: flutter

I am trying to complete [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#3) Flutter Code Lab, but the icons do not appear in my application. But they appears in Android Studio code:[image]
I have been included the lib in my file `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: startup_namer
description: A new Flutter application.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  english_words: ^3.1.0
```

But result is this:[image]

My main.dart file looks like this:

```
// Add the heart icons to the ListView.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

   ..... 

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);

    return new ListTile(
      title: new Text(
        pair.asPascalCase,
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
      trailing: new Icon(
        alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
        size: 22.0,
      ),
      onTap: () {      
        setState(() {
          if (alreadySaved) {
            _saved.remove(pair);
          } else {
            _saved.add(pair);
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I thought that is because I use iOS emulator, but when I tried with Android emulator the result was the same.

Comment: can you show more code around the icon?

Comment: silly me I did not provide my .dart file :), Sorry

Comment: I cant see any problems. First I would remove the color property and see if that works. Than I would the icon somewhere else with the same property to see if the problem is in ListTile. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Does your `pubspec.yaml` includes a `uses-material-design: true` in the flutter part ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet , no, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

(Copied from the comments)

You need to set `uses-material-design: true` in `pubspec.yaml` for the icons to be included in the app.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I have written `uses-material-design: true` in **pubspec.yaml** file. I am able to solve this problem by restarting the Android emulator. You can also try by uninstalling old build from your emulator and then installing the new one.

This is little weird behavior, but it works for me.

Comment: strange..but helped

Comment: it happen to me as well , in development thats ok to restart and work again, but i just publish in app store and icons are not rendering :/

Answer (score 4):

Hot reloading does not show changes in resources. Press the stop button square red color in the top action menu bar of android studio and run the app again.

[image: red icon highlighted by black circle]
It works.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that before and it helped fix my error!

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

1. Stopping the app
2. Running flutter clean in your app directory
3. Deleting the app from your simulator / emulator / device
4. Rebuild & Deploy the app.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter: 
  uses-material-design: true
```

Took me a while to figure out based on the answers above that `uses-material-design` is a property of `flutter`, not of the root.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the FlutterIcons library, make sure that your font-family in your pubspec.yaml matches the one declared in the `my_flutter_app_icons.dart` file.

Answer (score 2):

I assume we're talking about the [flutter_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons) package?

I had to kill the app entirely and reinstall it and they started working for me. Not sure why a hot reload didn't do the trick.

Comment: Because flutter would cache the fonts sometimes. You need to run `flutter clean` sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the App from emulator/physical device on which you are working and again build the app.
It works for me and will surely works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Icon changing to Chinese character was resolved by adding the correct path to the fonts folder. Specify, the correct path to your fonts folder by providing proper indentations:

- Flutter Clean
- Remove Build From your testing device/Emulator
- Run the app

Answer (score 1):

You need to set uses-material-design: true in pubspec.yaml for the icons to be included in the app.

Be sure to have a uses-material-design: true entry in the flutter section of your pubspec. yaml file. It allows you to use the predefined set of Material icons. Many Material Design widgets need to be inside of a MaterialApp to display properly, in order to inherit theme data.

Answer (score 0):

this was issue for me

Make sure in pubspec.yaml  file all the images and fonts have correct path and if you have added new image recently try to remove that and then rebuild

Answer (score 0):

The icons were loading normally on all devices except android for me. To fix it I simply:

**Before**

```
Icon(
       Icons.chevron_left,
          size: 40.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
```

[image]

**After**

```
  Icon(

       MdiIcons.chevronLeft,
          size: 40.0,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
```

[image]

**Steps**

1. Add to pubspec yahml

dependencies:
material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955

2. Add this to the file you want the icon

import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';

3. Instead of Icons.NameHere use MdiIcon.NameHere

Answer (score 0):

if all the above not worked then run
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main