# Problem: Flutter icons do not appear on my application? (only on my PC)

Tags: flutter, icons

I wonder why icons do not appear in my application when I compile it?

[image]

I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786982/flutter-icons-do-not-show), but did not find my answer there.
But solution of there not help me.

Note: The code compile and work fine on my colleague PC, but me nether.

My code looks like this:

```
    Positioned(
    top: _top,
    left: 30,
    right: 30,
    child:
      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <
          Widget>[
    Container(
        width: _btn1w,
        height: _btn1h,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                
              },
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.person_add,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 85.0,
              ),
              shape: new CircleBorder(),
              elevation: 2.0,
              fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Register',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 17,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )),
    Container(
      width: _btn2w,
      height: _btn2h,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: _margin),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              //
              _margin = 0;
              
            },
            child: new Icon(
              Icons.vpn_key,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 85.0,
            ),
            shape: new CircleBorder(),
            elevation: 2.0,
            fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned `colleague` you can check the assets added in `pubspec.yaml` and check all file included into `pubspec.yaml` exists on you PC to. may he/she forget to add them to version controller.

for example:

```
  assets:
    - assets/img/logo.png
```

added but You can't find `logo.png` in the `img` folder.
In this situnation `Flutter` compile your project but `icons` will be lose.

we had same problems too.

Comment: @Mobina I don't know how but it's a problem. I almost sure his problem is lossing assets.

Comment: Tnx, You saved my life ❤️

Comment: Sure, but I wanna know why it happens @A1Gard

Comment: @Mobina It's a problem on linking assets, when one or some assets lost, then ignore other assets too. I don't have enough time to PR, You can PR it.